# Application of Euler's theorem apart from finding last digits of huge numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, big-list, totient-function

I am looking for clever applications of [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem). On browsing the internet, I see that nearly all the applications of the theorem asks for finding last few digits of a huge number. The only other application I could find was [Euler's  Proof of Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Euler.27s_proof_by_infinite_descent). which uses Fermat's little theorem ( A weaker form of Euler's totient Theorem) and infinite descent.

This makes me wonder if we could find more uses for the theorem?

PS: I am interested in undergraduate level theorems/problems which could be solved using Euler's theorem (along with other technique, if necessary) Please mention suitable hints along with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one possible example. As $\phi(m)$ is the number of natural numbers less than $m$ which are coprime to $m$, Euler's theorem provides a good upper bound to a lot of problems which involve coprime numbers.

For example, if we consider the problem of Quadratic Congruence, solving the equation $x^{2} \equiv a\ (mod\ p)$, where p is a prime. Solving this problem using a number of algorithms require finding a non-residue $z$ of p first. It can be shown that there are $\phi(\phi(m))$ quadratic residues for m, hence the probability of finding a non-quadratic residue for a given p is quite high in practice. Even, for a composite $m$, checking if  $a$ is a quadratic residue of $m$ uses the following criteria, which is based on Euler's theorem:

**Euler's Criterion:** The equation $x^{2} \equiv a \ (mod\ m)$ has a solution if and only if

$a^{\frac{\phi(m)}{2}} \equiv 1 \ (mod\ m)$

As another example, I'd like to say that, finding a primitive root modulo $m$ has also a good use of Euler's theorem, the testing for primitive-rootness modulo $m$ exploits Euler's theorem and Lagrange's theorem equally.

Answer (score 1):

This application is maybe not for undergrads, but if you take Hensel's lemma for granted, it's a nice application, in my opinion.

**Hensel's lemma**: Let $f(t)$ be a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the $p$-adic integers, $p$ prime). If there exists $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(a)\equiv0\pmod{p}$ and $f'(a)\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$, then there exists an unique $b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(b)=0$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{p}$.

From this follows that there exist $p-1$ different elements $\theta$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $\theta^{p-1}=1$: these are the roots of unity.

To prove this, take $f(t)=t^{p-1}-1$ and $a$ integer with $1\leq a\leq p-1$. From Eulers theorem it follows that $f(a)\equiv0\pmod{p}$ from which a root of unity in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

An important application of *Euler's Theorem* is the *RSA Cryptosystem*. See the paper *[A Modern Day Application of Euler’s Theorem: The RSA Cryptosystem](http://www.gcsu.edu/math/docs/2012Capstone/maxey.pdf)* by M. Maxey for some information about it.

You may also find some helpful information in *[A Concrete Introduction to Higher Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387745270)* by L.N. Childs. The chapter $10$ *Applications of Euler’s Theorem* is subdivied into  three sections

- *[RSA Cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))*
- *[Pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime)*
- *[The Pollard $p-1$ Factoring Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm)*